# Snap7 module not found with python .exe

Tags: python, snap7

I'm using Pycharm to create a simple program that uses snap7 lib. to read a S7-1200 PLC, it works correctly when i run it with Pycharm but when i try to run it with an .exe file it prompts this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snap7'

the snap7.dll and .lib are both in sys32 folder aswell as in environment variables PATH route.
both the python file and my PC are x64 so i used the x64 version of the DLL and lib files.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the snap7 library?

`py -m pip install python-snap7` is the way i installed it. I never had any problems with it.